# How to do something with data from stdin, line by line, a maximum number of times and printing the number of line in Haskell

Tags: haskell, monads

This code reads the number of lines to process from the first line of stdin, then it loops number_of_lines_to_process times doing some calculations and prints the result.
I want it to print the line number in "Line #" after "#" but I don't know how to obtain it

```
import IO
import Control.Monad (replicateM)

main :: IO ()

main = do
    hSetBuffering stdin LineBuffering
    s <- getLine
    let number_of_lines_to_process = read s :: Integer
    lines <- replicateM (fromIntegral(number_of_lines_to_process)) $ do
        line <- getLine
        let number = read line :: Integer
            result = number*2 --example
        putStrLn ("Line #"++": "++(show result)) --I want to print the number of the iteration and the result
    return ()
```

I guess that the solution to this problem is really easy, but I'm not familiar with Haskell (coding in it for the first time) and I didn't find any way of doing this. Can anyone help?

Comment: Preparing for Google Code Jam? :)

Comment: @Rotsor Nope, but close. I'm currently on another programming competition :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use [`forM_`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad.html#v%3aforM-95-) instead of `replicateM`:

```
import IO
import Control.Monad

main :: IO ()
main = do
    hSetBuffering stdin LineBuffering
    s <- getLine
    let number_of_lines_to_process = read s :: Integer

    forM_ [1..number_of_lines_to_process] (\i -> do
        line <- getLine
        let number = read line :: Integer
            result = number * 2
        putStrLn $ "Line #" ++ show i ++ ": " ++ show result)
```

Note that because you use `forM_` (which discards the results of each iteration) you don't need the additional `return ()` at the end - the `do` block returns the value of the last statement, which in this case is the `()` which is returned by `forM_`.

Comment: No problem. Aside: I'd be interested to know why this was downvoted.

Answer (score 9):

The trick is to first create a list of all the line numbers you want to print, and to then loop through that list, printing each number in turn. So, like this:

```
import Control.Monad

import System.IO

main :: IO ()
main = do
  hSetBuffering stdin LineBuffering
  s <- getLine
  let lineCount = read s :: Int
      -- Create a list of the line numbers
      lineNumbers = [1..lineCount]

  -- `forM_` is like a "for-loop"; it takes each element in a list and performs
  -- an action function that takes the element as a parameter
  forM_ lineNumbers $ \ lineNumber -> do
    line <- getLine
    let number = read line :: Integer
        result = number*2 --example
    putStrLn $ "Line #" ++ show lineNumber ++ ": " ++ show result
  return ()
```

Read the definition of [`forM_`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad.html#v:forM_).

By the way, I wouldn't recommend using the old Haskell98 IO library. Use `System.IO` instead.

Answer (score 5):

You could calculate the results, enumerate them, and then print them:

```
import IO
import Control.Monad (replicateM)

-- I'm assuming you start counting from zero
enumerate xs = zip [0..] xs

main :: IO ()

main = do
    hSetBuffering stdin LineBuffering
    s <- getLine
    let number_of_lines_to_process = read s :: Integer
    lines <- replicateM (fromIntegral(number_of_lines_to_process)) $ do
        line <- getLine
        let number = read line :: Integer
            result = number*2 --example
        return result
    mapM_ putStrLn [ "Line "++show i++": "++show l | (i,l) <- enumerate lines ]
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm still new at Haskell, so there could be problems with the program below (it does work). This program is a tail recursive implementation. The `doLine` helper function carries around the line number. The processing step is factored into `process`, which you can change according to the problem you are presented.

```
import System.IO
import Text.Printf

main = do
  hSetBuffering stdin LineBuffering
  s <- getLine
  let number_of_lines_to_process = read s :: Integer
  processLines number_of_lines_to_process
  return ()

-- This reads "max" lines from stdin, processing each line and
-- printing the result.
processLines :: Integer -> IO ()
processLines max = doLine 0
    where doLine i
              | i == max = return ()
              | otherwise =
                  do
                    line <- getLine
                    let result = process line
                    Text.Printf.printf "Line #%d: %d\n" (i + 1) result
                    doLine (i + 1)


-- Just an example. (This doubles the input.)
process :: [Char] -> Integer
process line = let number = read line :: Integer
               in
                 number * 2
```

I'm a haskell rookie, so any critiques of the above are welcome.

Comment: You don't have to use the `i` variable in your code; just decrement the `max` variable on each iteration and check whether it is 0. You can also use pattern matching and `where`-clauses in some places instead of `if..then..else`-expressions and `let..in` expressions.

Comment: @dflemstr: If I don't have `i`, how will I print the line number?

Comment: My only quibble is your claim that "no monads are needed". You are using the IO monad all over the place (the hint is the word `do`, which is syntactic sugar for the chaining together of monadic functions with the `>>=` and `>>` operators).

Comment: @bstpierre, good point. However, using `forM_` will remove that issue altogether, and I personally think that it's a "cleaner" solution.

Comment: @ChrisTaylor: True; I was referring to iteration, not IO, which obviously needs the monads.

Comment: @dflemstr: Thanks for the suggestions. I rewrote `processLines` to use patterns and internalized the helper function.

Answer (score 0):

Just as an alternative, I thought that you might enjoy an answer with minimal monad mucking and no **do** notation.  We zip a lazy list of the user's data with an infinite list of the line number using the enumerate function to give us our desired output.

```
import System.IO
import Control.Monad (liftM)

--Here's the function that does what you really want with the data
example = (* 2)

--Enumerate takes a function, a line number, and a line of input and returns
--an ennumerated line number of the function performed on the data
enumerate :: (Show a, Show b, Read a) => (a->b) -> Integer -> String -> String
enumerate f i x = "Line #" ++ 
                  show i ++ 
                  ": " ++ 
                  (show . f . read $ x) -- show . f . read handles our string conversion

-- Runover takes a list of lines and runs 
-- an enumerated version of the sample over those lines.
-- The first line is the number of lines to process.
runOver :: [String] -> [String]
runOver (line:lines) = take (read line) $ --We only want to process the number of lines given in the first line
                       zipWith (enumerate example) [1..] lines -- run the enumerated example 
                                                               -- over the list of numbers and the list of lines

-- In our main, we'll use liftM to lift our functions into the IO Monad
main = liftM (runOver . lines) getContents
```